# iText - Como Usar "For Each" em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Estou tentando usar o *"For Each"* para gerar vários PDF's, como uma Mala Direta do Word. Minha ideia é selecionar vários nomes da *ListBox* e gerar os PDFs com os itens selecionados.
Meu código está assim:

```
Dim listarNomes As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

        Dim data As String() = {listarNomes}

        For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1
            doc.NewPage()
            doc.Add(gif)
            doc.Add(New Paragraph(" "))
            doc.Add(New Paragraph(data(i), fonte1))

        Next
```

Mesmo quando eu seleciono vários nomes do *ListBox*, só gera uma página com apenas um nome. 
Minha *ListBox* usa *Itens de Associação de Dados*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um `For Each` dentro de `ListBox.SelectedItems`:

```vb
For Each listaItem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    Dim listarNomes As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(listaItem)

    Dim data As String() = {listarNomes}

    For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1
        doc.NewPage()
        doc.Add(gif)
        doc.Add(New Paragraph(" "))
        doc.Add(New Paragraph(data(i), fonte1))
    Next
Next
```

Desta forma, irá percorrer por todos os itens selecionados na sua `ListBox`, uma vez que esteja habilitado para selecionar vários itens.